# Examples for partially observable, sensorless environments

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, observable

I am currently looking at partially observable environments and sensor less problems as described in Artificial intelligence : a modern approach/ Stuart Russell, Peter Norvig.
Chapter 4.

The only example for partially observable and also sensorless problems i can find on the internet is the vacuum cleaner problem also shown in the book.

Is there another example, making it also possible to execute the mentioned algorithms as well?

Thanks,

SideSwipe

Comment: Why not impress us with your own efforts and invite us to add to them. That's generally a better approach on SO than 'plz help me think'.

Comment: My problem is that all the problems I can imagine are either just a ripoff of the vacuum cleaner example or unsolvable or not that nicely solvable.For example I thought of a door with two locks,that you can lock and unlock (clearly a simple ripoff).Then I had the idea to enable only the action TurnKey (and Move ofc), leaving you not knowing if the door was locked, which makes the problem unsolvable.I looked for other problems I know like the Traveling Salesman,the Cannibal, the Queen and the 8 Puzzle problem.The last eg isnt solvable sensorless,but solvable in a unnice way with one field known

Comment: And for most of the others I don't see any senseful lack of percept to make it a sensorless problem or partially observable.

Comment: It's not a particularly useful or interesting class of problem.  With no sensor, all problems are "partially observable," but only in the trivial sense of being not observable at all.  R+N will have a great deal to say about partially observable problems, but mostly in contexts where there's something to observe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind of problems you refer to are referred in the literature as "conformant" planning (partially observable, no feedback) problems. It's not a terribly "interesting" class of planning problems, because very little work has been done on them, compared with more expressive models such as contingent - partially observable, partial feedbak - planning.

There's been some work done on it in recent years and you can take a look at the benchmarks by Joerg Hoffmann over here: http://www.loria.fr/~hoffmanj/ff/cff-tests.tgz

A more interesting kind of "applications" of conformant planning is that of mapping the problem of designing a finite state controller into that of solving a conformant planning problem. You might want to check this paper:

http://www.dtic.upf.edu/~hgeffner/fsc-nectar-aaai-2010.pdf

I think there are some follow-ups to this.

Note that in the above the problems are described in STRIPS extended so to represent uncertainty in the initial state.